# switching boundary conditions to simulate a reciprocating flow in COMSOL

Tags: boundary-conditions, comsol

*This is a re-posted question which was poorly defined earlier*

I have been trying to simulate **reciprocating** flow of a convective fluid through a heated channel in COMSOL-Multiphysics. The schematic of the domain is as follows:

[image]

There is reciprocating flow of a convective fluid through the channel through the highlighted boundaries **L** and **R**, while it is being heated from the bottom $(q'')$. I will now explain the problem in more detail. A sinusoidal mass flux at some tempertature $T_i$ (only the positive values in the mass flux curve, otherwise zero where the sinusoid turns negative) has been defined at **L**. Similar mass flux profile with the same frequency, amplitude but with a phase lag of $\pi$ is applied at **R** . In this scenario, for a cycle of time-period $T$, the flow should reciprocate between **L** and **R**.

For the half cycle $0<t<T/2$, the boundary *L* should act as an inlet, while *R* should act as the oulet. During the next half of the cycle, i.e., $T/2<t<T$, the fluid enters from **R** and leaves through **L**. Thus **R** must now acts an inlet and **L** as the outlet.

It must also be noted that the simulation also models heat transfer. So for $0<t<T/2$, **L** should be acting as if it admits a fluid at temperature $T_f$ and **R** should act as the outlet (ususally modeled as zero conductive flux). The phenomenon will be opposite for the next half, i.e., $T/2<t<T$.

I want to achieve this switching of boundary condition in each half cycle inside a transient simulation in COMSOL, for some finite number of cycles until the system reaches a quasi-steady state.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Is the fluid compressible? Have you tried first setting up regular pipe flow with fixed direction of flow?

Comment: @MPIchael Appreciate the response. The fluid is incompressible. I regularly do internal flow simulations (with fixed direction of flow) on such geometry.

Comment: Can't you just change the sign of the amplitude of the boundary condition?